# Given html file extract just meaningful text

Tags: java, algorithm, nlp, jsoup

Given a standard html file which contains css links, image links etc how can just the meaningful text be extracted ? By meaningful I mean the text which is is relevant to the page. So in the case of StackOverflow, the question and answer texts. For a news site this would be the body of the story.

One algorithm could possibly use is to determine what is a sentence or not :  search for sequences of words that contain a capital letter at their beginning and full stop at end (crude but just something to get started).

What are the alternatives ?

Update : boilerpipe as suggested by @Vanaja Jayaraman appears to work well. I required to add following Maven dependencies for boilerpipe

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
    <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.21</version>
</dependency>
```

Code (Scala) to extract text :

```
  val source = scala.io.Source.fromFile("c:\\news1.html")
  val lines = source.mkString
  source.close()
println(de.l3s.boilerpipe.extractors.ArticleExtractor.INSTANCE.getText(lines));
```

Comment: Meaningful text differs between pages and what your interest in the particular page is. I think you need to define "meaningful" in a more precise way to get a good answer. Either do it in a general way such that it is the main text content of a page or do it in a more specific way such that you want only the Q&A from an SO page as in your example.

Comment: @Einar Sundgren the algorithm I defined should find both "main text content" & " Q&A ".

Comment: This gets very complex then since what can be considered "meaningful" differs from reader to reader. I would suggest you to start with some supervised machine learning determining what you/the user consider to be within the boundray of "meaningful". From the given training set you could possibly determine what is the meaningful parts for each user in an unknown set. What the parameters for the training set would be is also quite wide. Possbly html/css/js tags combined with basic nlp algorithms such as checking if n-grams constitutes valid parts of sentences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Boilerpipe](https://boilerpipe-web.appspot.com/)'s Article Extractor if your input is a news site. And some other extractor types also available in Boilerpipe.

In JSoup you can use selector concept.

Comment: thank you, this works well. I've updated answer with some additional info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML Selectors such as class, id, paragraph etc. you can get text by using .text(), HTML by calling .HTML. I scraped a site earlier which you can have a look [here](http://pastebin.com/UsM13JNa). It's a bit messy but it will help you.

[Here](http://www.javatpoint.com/jsoup-tutorial) is good Tutorial